# CSS content property not displaying

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I'm following a book example:

Iv'e copied the following from the book and saved it as HTML.
all the css properties seem to work except the "content" property which does not display.Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title> The content property </title>
        <style type='text/css' media='all'>
            div {
                content: "Hello, world!";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`content` is used with `:before` or `:after` like so:

```
div:after
{
    content: "Hello, world!";
}
```

Regardless, I've only used `content` for special cases (to clear floated elements, for example). I've never actually used this to insert content. You generally want to separate content and presentation anyway, so I think this is a bad idea. Which book are you reading? :)

Comment: Wiley - Wrox Beginning - Css - Cascading Style Sheets For Web Design (2005) and the text seems to do this more than once. Old book? Or just bad editing?

Comment: Red alert...  Cascading Style Sheets For Web Design (2005) ... soooo much has changed since 2005. I HIGHLY recommend getting a new book.

Comment: Thanks ... Old Library Book ... Will get new one :)

Comment: Or just go through thousands of online tutorials out there (make sure it's a credible site though :P)

Answer (score 17):

The `content` property only applies to CSS pseudo-elements such as `:before` and `:after`.

You cannot use it to set the content of an arbitrary element.

Comment: That answer is correct for all browsers but Opera. Tested with http://jsfiddle.net/H2LS6/

Answer (score 9):

The `content` property only works for `:before` and `:after` to prepend or append content to said nodes, like so:

```css
.email-address:before {
  content : "Email address: ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="email-address">myemail@gmail.com</li>
</ul>
```

The output would be

• Email address: myemail@gmail.com