# False '0' prefixed octal literal within embedded strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following code contains a string within a string. Since the bodies of es6 classes are in strict mode, it fails to compile due to the inner string looking like it contains an octal value.

```
class Test {
  static get template () { return `
    .class {
      content: "\2713\0020"
    }
  `}
}
```

Workarounds include escaping the string or using characters in their non-unicode form.

My workflow involves creating the HTML and CSS in a fiddle, then copy-pasting the code into an encapsulating es6 class (I'm limited to using a single file).

Is there anything I can do to avoid the error? I was hoping to wrap the string but it is still within the class body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `String.raw` with the template literal, so that the backslashes are interpreted as literal backslashes, not escape characters:

```js
class Test {
  static get template () { return String.raw`
    .class:before {
      content: "\2713\0020"
    }
  `}
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = Test.template;
```

```html
<div class="class">text</div>
```

(note that `content` only applies to [`:before` and `:after`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6727795) psuedo-elements)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could put `u` after `\`:

```js
"use strict";

class Test {
  static get template () { return `
    .class {
      content: "\u2713\u0020"
    }
  `}
}

console.log(Test.template)
```